# Package geometry error using Beamer and TeXworks

Tags: beamer, geometry, texworks, paper-size

I am trying to create a beamer presentation using TeXworks.
I have done this several times before in Overleaf, but for several reasons I am trying to learn to use a local LaTeX distribution.
I'm writing the code in `TeXworks` and typesetting via `pdfLaTeX` and my distribution is `TeX Live`

Here is a MWE and the error that I am getting is `! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short` and `! Package geometry Error: \paperheight (0.0pt) too short`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The complete `.log` file is too long to include, so I have copied what seem to be relevant to the issue and I am happy to provide a copy of the whole thing should you request.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.1.17)  26 NOV 2023 22:02
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**untitled-3.tex
(./untitled-3.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-12-17>
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2022/09/13 v3.68 A class for typesetting presentations
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count185
)
\beamer@tempbox=\box51
\beamer@tempcount=\count186
\c@beamerpauses=\count187

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty
\beamer@slideinframe=\count188
\beamer@minimum=\count189
\beamer@decode@box=\box52
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box53
\beamer@modecount=\count190
)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
\headdp=\dimen140
\footheight=\dimen141
\sidebarheight=\dimen142
\beamer@tempdim=\dimen143
\beamer@finalheight=\dimen144
\beamer@animht=\dimen145
\beamer@animdp=\dimen146
\beamer@animwd=\dimen147
\beamer@leftmargin=\dimen148
\beamer@rightmargin=\dimen149
\beamer@leftsidebar=\dimen150
\beamer@rightsidebar=\dimen151
\beamer@boxsize=\dimen152
\beamer@vboxoffset=\dimen153
\beamer@descdefault=\dimen154
\beamer@descriptionwidth=\dimen155
\beamer@lastskip=\skip48
\beamer@areabox=\box54
\beamer@animcurrent=\box55
\beamer@animshowbox=\box56
\beamer@sectionbox=\box57
\beamer@logobox=\box58
\beamer@linebox=\box59
\beamer@sectioncount=\count191
\beamer@subsubsectionmax=\count192
\beamer@subsectionmax=\count193
\beamer@sectionmax=\count194
\beamer@totalheads=\count195
\beamer@headcounter=\count196
\beamer@partstartpage=\count197
\beamer@sectionstartpage=\count198
\beamer@subsectionstartpage=\count199
\beamer@animationtempa=\count266
\beamer@animationtempb=\count267
\beamer@xpos=\count268
\beamer@ypos=\count269
\beamer@ypos@offset=\count270
\beamer@showpartnumber=\count271
\beamer@currentsubsection=\count272
\beamer@coveringdepth=\count273
\beamer@sectionadjust=\count274
\beamer@toclastsection=\count275
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\count276

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip49
\beamer@paperheight=\skip50

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count277
\Gm@cntv=\count278
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count279
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen156
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen157
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen158
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen159
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen160
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen161
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen162
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen163
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17


! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.

See the geometry package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1006 \Gm@process
                  
? 

! Package geometry Error: \paperheight (0.0pt) too short.

See the geometry package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.

See the geometry package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.145   \geometry{includeheadfoot}
                                  
? 

! Package geometry Error: \paperheight (0.0pt) too short.

See the geometry package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.145   \geometry{includeheadfoot}
```

What is really confusing to me is that (i) I am not using the `geometry` package (that I am aware of) and (ii) the first line of the `.log` file says "This is pdftex, Version..." when I am compiling the presentation by `pdfLaTeX`.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine for me. Are you sure that exact same code produces a log file too long to post? To answer your questions: (i) `beamer` uses `geometry` and (ii) `pdflatex` is a symbolic link to `pdftex`.

Comment: What result do you get from `kpsewhich geometry.cfg`?

Comment: @cfr, Thank you for your response. Yes when I try to compile the MWE, I get a very long log file and several blank pages of output. When I enter `kpsewhich geometry.cfg` in my terminal, nothing happens. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Hmm. Nothing is OK. If it found something, that might be the problem. Can you post the complete log you get when compiling the code in your question? If it doesn't fit, use a paste bin (https://0x0.st/ is good) and post the link.

Comment: @cfr Okay here is [a link](https://pastebin.com/C3xLkz9q) to a paste bin of the log file. It will expire in 1 day.

Comment: [And please use a less obnoxious pastebin site. That one features ads and pop ups.]

Comment: I uninstalled TeX Live and reinstalled TeX Live 2023 and now it compiles with no issue.
@cfr, how do I make it known that this problem has been solved?

Comment: Great. I turned my comment into an answer so you can accept it to mark the problem as solved. [Disclaimer: I will gain 'points' if you do this. You will also gain some. ] You should see a greyed-out tick at the top left of the answer. You click on it to turn it green.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using some newer files with an older installation of TeX Live. I.e. TL is 2022, but the format date is January 2023 and PGF is version 3.1.10 from 2023-01-15. That suggests you've installed TL 2023 files into an existing TL 2022. If you were going to try this, you shouldn't install the newer files into the main TL 2022 tree.

I suggest installing TeX Live 2023 and making sure to only touch the distribution directories with `tlmgr`.

If you want to use other stuff or experiment with newer releases, keep them in your working directory or install in `TEXMFHOME` or `TEXMFLOCAL`.

Note that it is perfectly possible to have multiple years of TeX Live installed side-by-side so you can switch between them. The problems only arise if you mis updated stuff into an older version. For example, I currently have TeX Live 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023 installed under `/usr/local/texlive`, but I don't touch those trees. Anything not from the distribution, I put under `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` or (for anything which isn't font-related) `~/texmf`.